# Asp.net core opens razor pages, which I have deleted

Tags: razor-pages, asp.net-core-6.0

I scaffolded some ASP.NET Core Identity razor pages, including some in Manage subfolder. I deleted most of them and moved all needing functionality to the Manage page in Account folder. This is my current [structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/maCbU.png). But asp.net core can open me this [page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SFNUB.png), which contains a list group with all pages I have deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Identity UI package includes a range of pages with examples of different workflows. When you install the package, all of the UI is made available to your application whether you need it or not. Scaffolding gives you the opportunity to customise pages in the package. The scaffolded version overrides the version in the package. If you delete the scaffolded version, processing falls back to the package version.

If you want to disable parts of the UI package, you can use Authorization to block access to them, perhaps by specifying a non-existent role, or you can scaffold the pages and return a `NotFoundResult` from `OnGet` and `OnPost` handlers in the individual pages.